# como comparar com javascript dois campos datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Preciso comparar dois campos no meu html que estão com datepicker. Segue o meu código abaixo:

```
    var inicio = $("#Periodo_De").datepicker("getDate");
    var final = $("#Periodo_Ate").datepicker("getDate");

    if (inicio > final) {
      console.log('inicio é maior que final');
    }
```

Comment: O que está saindo errado? Aparece algum erro no console?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi ele esta comparando no padrao americano e o meu datepicker esta no brasileiro... acho que terei que comparar dia/mes/ano para funcionar

Comment: acho que se você formatar `ANOCOMPLETO-MES-DIA` para esse tipo de verificação pode funcionar.

Comment: Segundo a [documentação](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) não, esse método retorna objeto `Date` (e quando você compara 2 desses, está comparando um valor em milissegundos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio eu que você deve saber que para o `datapicker` funcionar você deve acrescentar as libs dele...

No caso, além do `JQuery` estou usando a biblioteca `JQuery-UI`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Código HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inicio" name="inicio">
<input type="text" id="final" name="final">

<input type="button" id="testar" name="testar" value="testar">
```

Código JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#inicio').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
    $('#final').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
});

$("#testar").click(function() {
    var inicio = $('#inicio').val();
    var final = $('#final').val();

    if (inicio > final) {
        alert('inicio é maior que final');
    }else{
        alert('final é maior que inicio');
    }
});
```

[Aqui no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxfw27u6/4/) um exemplo do `datapicker` funcionando do jeito que você necessita...